# manage jenkins don't appear on Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I downloaded `Jenkins.war` and I put it in `tomcat/webapps` directory. I launch `http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins`.

I created the first job by configuring jenkins and the job too. Everything worked well and I went to "manage jenkins" for putting all permissions for everyone but I lost all permissions and to access to manage jenkins too.

Please, What should I do for having all options in "Manage Jenkins".

Answer (score 3):

If you need to temporarily disable the security, so that you have admin access again, you can follow the steps on the [disable security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) wiki page:

> Stop Jenkins.
>   Go to `$JENKINS_HOME` in the file system and find `config.xml`.
>   In this file, find the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` element.
>   Replace `true` with `false`.
>   Remove the elements `authorizationStrategy` and `securityRealm`.
>   Start Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is reset security.

```
Tomcat by default stores the user database in an XML file called $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml. You can add the following lines to this file to create an admin user.
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="jenkins-admin" password="secret" roles="admin"/>
```

Then just restart Jenkins, go to admin panel and set everything once again.